# Void Parameter Type Causes Missing Type Error

Tags: c++, sdk, void

Here is the prototype:

```
void RecvProxy_ToggleSights( const CRecvProxyData* pData, void* pStruct, void* pOut );
```

And then the function itself:

```
void RecvProxy_ToggleSights( const CRecvProxyData* pData, void* pStruct, void* pOut ){

CBaseCombatWeapon *pWeapon = (CBaseCombatWeapon*)pStruct;
if( pData->m_Value.m_Int )
    pWeapon->EnableIronsights();
else
    pWeapon->DisableIronsights();}
```

And then the error message this code, both the prototype and the definition, generates:

> Error 19  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   f:\Mods\CI Testbed\src\game\shared\basecombatweapon_shared.cpp  47

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The file `basecombatweapon_shared.cpp` is using some types that are not defined. This is probably because you got the `#include` dependencies messed up (i.e. missing some, or some in the wrong order).

Comment: The code given is fine (and void* is perfectly valid). Are you sure it's not another function and a macro is adding lines to your code? Also, have a look around to make sure all functions have a return value.

Comment: Which of the given lines is line 47? Is it possible that you haven't properly #included one of the types you're using here?

Comment: @pragnar See the posted pastebin link below for the entireit of the .cpp file the above snippets came from.  The prototype is line 47.  The function is much further down on line 2594.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the type 'CRecvProxyData' defined? Your code is otherwise correct (assuming all user defined types are defined properly), although I suggest you place opening and closing braces for the function definition on their own lines.

Also, I take issue with void*: It's a bit of a hangover from C, you should aim to eliminate it from your source code where necessary. Could you use polymorphism or templates instead?

It's likely your missing a #include, or have made an error in your include guards. If you could post the contents of the filer where 'CRecvProxyData' is defined as well as the code surrounding that which you have posted, that would be a great help. Otherwise, I can only speculate :).

Comment: Here is where CRecvProxyData is defined: `// This is passed into RecvProxy functions.
class CRecvProxyData
{
public:
 const RecvProp *m_pRecvProp;  // The property it's receiving.

 DVariant  m_Value;   // The value given to you to store.

 int    m_iElement;   // Which array element you're getting.

 int    m_ObjectID;   // The object being referred to.
};`  I will also post a pastbin link to the entity of the cpp file the original code is from.

Comment: It looks like that definition (of `CRecvProxyData` is coming out of `dt_recv.h`, however that header isn't included in your source.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this, I think DRH is correct: the definition for CRecvProxyData likely exists in a header file that is not included in the source file you've shown us, and as such causing the error. To be honest, that's the only possible cause I can see.

Comment: @DRH Wow, that actually fixed it.  There are other errors but they are of the same type as this one so know I know how to fix them.  Thanks!  I have been trying to figure this out for a year and a half on and off.